# RegEx to read multiple %%TAG%%

Tags: regex

I'm trying to extract tags from a string.

The string is in following format:
`bla bla %%TAG1%% bla %%TAG2%% bla bla bla`

My RegEx: `%%.*%%`

The problem is, if there are multiple tags in same line, it only reads both tags together as one tag.

`%%TAG1%% bla %%TAG2%%` while i need both separate.

Comment: Use lazy matching if you do not want to complicate it further: `%%.*?%%`

Comment: Thanks! Thats what I needed.